# Create new cell values according to conditional

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with VBA code that will set a conditional in a new column for my dataset.

Basically, if cell AB2 contains "iMac" or "MacBook", then write "iMac" or "MacBook" (respectively) in cell AD2. Then do this for the entire dataset. Note: Column AB is a list of item descriptions, of which I'm only interested in iMacs and MacBooks.

```
Dim celltxt As String
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("AB2").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "iMac") Then
    Range("AD2").Select
    Selection.Value = "iMac"
ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "MacBook") Then
    Range("AD2").Select
    Selection.Value = "MacBook"
End If
Range("AD2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD2:AD" & lastRow)
```

I have a feeling that you can't AutoFill an if-else...

If there's a better way to approach this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("iMac",AB2))),"iMac",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("MacBook",AB2))),"MacBook","Not sure what product, but not an iMac or MacBook"))`

Comment: @BigBen that should be an answer of its own :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a function. Add this:

```
Function FindModel(Expr As String) As String
    For Each Model In Array("iMac", "MacBook")
        If InStr(1, Expr, Model, vbTextCompare) Then
            FindModel = Model
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and then use it like this: `=FindModel(AB2)` in your sheet

Answer (score 1):

For kicks and giggles...

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("iMac",AB2))),"iMac",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("MacBook",AB2))),"MacBook","Not sure what product, but not an iMac or MacBook"))
```

Comment: In this sense, you *can* AutoFill an If...Then...Else

Comment: I meant a "manual" AutoFill, which you can do from the menu or double-clicking the corner of the cell, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter`:

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .range("AB1:AB" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="iMac", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="MacBook"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```